# Implementing reading discussion threads for pros/grads/academics

Tags: discussion

I've just come from a [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/73664/reference-request-formal-abstract-theory-of-evolution) on the main site looking for references to a formal text on evolutionary theory. I answered with some of my own favourite books. It did get me thinking, however, that it might be nice to have some formal framework for the discussion of classic works (in any subfield), where those who have read the text can give some opinions on it, and others can debate/discuss.

My rationale for this comes from reading through the meta threads concerning if Biology.SE is too populated with laymen and not used enough by professional biologists. I thought that one way to address this might be to get the professional biologists on here discussing more of the classic literature from various fields amongst themselves. It may even serve to draw more graduate-level biologists to the site, if there is quality discussion.

If people think that this is far beyond the possible scope of Biology.SE, does anyone know of any online forums where such discussion takes place? Of course we (grad students, academics) often get this in the university environment, but it would be great to have some kind of supplemental online environment.

Comment: Discussion is never the purpose of SE, being a strictly Q&A site. I can't answer for external sites, but beyond main site, there's always [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=biology.stackexchange.com) for users with 20 rep to discuss anything (hopefully it's related to the site's topic though)